# Is there a way to copy a repo without forking but retaining the commit history?

Tags: git, github

I created a web app template repo that I want to use as the basis for a new project.  I don't want to fork the repo because I don't want my project to show up as a fork in GitHub and I never intend to submit PRs into the repo I'm using as a template.  But I also don't want to just copy the files because then I'll lose the commit history.

So, is there a way to copy the repo in such a way that I'm not forking but I'm also retaining the commit history?

Comment: Clone it (`git clone`) and push it to the copy location.

Comment: @Guildenstern Thank you! If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: There's also the option to mark the repo as a [template repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository), and you can pick if you want to retain history or not when you create a repo from it. The new repo will indicate that it was created from the template.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you!  if you add that as an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Oh, actually, you can't choose if you want to retain history or now when creating a repo from a template: you can choose if you want to copy all branches or not, but the new repo starts with a single commit in any case. If you want history, you do have to clone and push manually.

Comment: You can just copy `.git` folder and work with it as a new repo. Not to forget to change remote repos (if present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone it (`git clone`) and push it to the copy location.

GitHub won't treat it like a fork unless you go through the fork mechanism.